# Raise user defined Exception in Python that only terminates program on condition

Tags: python, exception

I have a module defining a class that inherits from `Exception`. This module is used extensively by me and others in my organization, and it is now clear that for some well-defined conditions it would be appropriate that the program issue a warning and continue execution rather than terminating execution when the exception is raised.

It is desirable *not* to require all users to add `try-except` clauses everywhere this exception is used to manage when execution is allowed to continue. The condition is passed to the exception when raised.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

```
class ConditionalException(Exception):
  def __init__(self,condition):
    self.condition=condition
    pass

  def __str__(self):
    return 'Condition: {}'.format(self.condition)


def raiseConditionalException():
  condition=0
  raise ConditionalException(condition) # should just give warning and continue execution

  condition=1
  raise ConditionalException(condition) # should be fatal

  condition=2
  raise ConditionalException(condition) # should never reach this point


raiseConditionalException()
```

Is this possible, or is it completely contrary to the principle of raising an Exception, and requiring that the user be explicit when handling exceptions?

I tried looking at the Exception and BaseException class definitions (https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) and I haven't been able to discern exactly what happens when an exception is raised (e.g. what methods internal to `Exception` built-in class that might be able to be modified in user-defined exception).

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I should mention, if it's possible to inherit from a different class, like `Warning` (although I think `Warning` inherits from `BaseException` too, so I'm not sure how to make raising a warning non-fatal), and accomplish the same desired result then that's fine too. I tried inheriting from `Warning` and it still acts like I inherited from `Exception`.

An interesting detail is when I type `help(Exception)`, the first thing it says is

```
class Exception(BaseException)
 |  Common base class for all non-exit exceptions.
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Exception
 |      BaseException
 |      object
```

It says **non-exit**??? What does non-exit mean if not that it doesn't exit?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it should be the exception's job.

Comment: "Non-exit" refers to exceptions that it's likely reasonable to handle, as opposed to things like `SystemExit` or `GeneratorExit`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a warning, use a warning. Don't raise an exception. Define a separate warning class:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    ...

class MyWarning(Warning):
    ...
```

and use `warnings.warn` instead of `raise` when you want to warn instead of raising:

```
warnings.warn("Oh no, bad things!", MyWarning)
```

Your attempt to use `Warning` failed because you still tried to `raise` the warning instead of going through the warning system.

Comment: Since the `Warning` class inherits from `Exception`, I guess I'd expect `raise Warning` to make sense as a non-exiting (as in, doesn't terminate the program), or *potentially* non-exiting operation. I don't understand what is the point of having a separate `Warning` class if it's inheriting from `Exception` and it can't be used the same way with `raise`.

Comment: @jpf: Warnings inherit from `Exception` because there's a setting to turn warnings into errors. In that case, `warnings.warn` will `raise` the warning. You should not `raise` warnings yourself under normal circumstances.

Comment: So `raise` implies termination of the program when `except` doesn't prevent termination, right? This issue with `Warning` inheriting from `Exception` is really semantically dissatisfying. It's like `Animal` inheriting from `Insect`, rather than the other way 'round. (unless `Exception` were allowed to be non-terminating without `except` clause)